# @Indexed annotation is ignored

Tags: spring-data-solr

I have a simple Product class as it follows

```
@SolrDocument(collection = "product")
public class Product {
  @Id
  @Indexed(name = "id", type = "string")
  private String id;
  @Field
    @Indexed(name = "namex", type = "text_general", stored = false, searchable=true)
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

my problem is that the annotation @Indexed is completely ignored. The name of the field is simply name (instead of namex) and the field is stored. Any guess?

**UPDATE 1** if I remove the type annotation name works, but stored has no effect still

Answer (score 0):

I managed by modifying the bean that creates the SolrTemplate object like follows:

```
@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
    SolrTemplate st = new SolrTemplate(client);
    st.setSchemaCreationFeatures(Collections.singletonList(Feature.CREATE_MISSING_FIELDS));
    st.afterPropertiesSet();
    return st;
}
```